# Lua help off switch

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Hi im totally new to scripting. im using this currently and it works the way i want even with the error, moves down only once on each press. What i want is if i press "v" it will turn "numlock" off if its on and leave off if off. Help would be great

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
        if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1)then
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
                repeat
                    MoveMouseRelative(0, 30)
                    Sleep(10)
                    MoveMouseRelative(0, 30)
                    Sleep(10)
                    MoveMouseRelative(0, 30)
                    Sleep(10)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed()
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i want is if i press "v"

GHUB is unable to handle press/release of usual keys on the keyboard (digits, letters).
GHUB allows you to write handle for:

- mouse buttons (on Logitech mouse)
- special G-keys and M-keys (on Logitech keyboard)

In other words, GHUB is unable to do something when user presses <kbd>V</kbd>

---

> it will turn "numlock" off if its on and leave off if off

You can do this, for example, on mouse button 5 press:

```
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
   if IsKeyLockOn"NumLock" then
      PressAndReleaseKey"NumLock"
   end
end
```